How to send EEG triggers in OpenSesame to a serial port
I need to send EEG triggers in OpenSesame to this serial port as shown:

I tried using pySerial. The code I used is:
import serial
serialport = serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
serialport.write (bytes ([101]))

All of the parameters have been tested and confirmed to be correct, but I didn't see any triggers in the BrainVision's recorder.
Then, I decided to try using psychopy-labhackers. The installation was successful and I also restarted the kernal, but I couldn’t import the module. When I tried to import labhackers, it shows an error 'No module named labhackers'.
pip install psychopy-labhackers 
import labhackers

The path that psychopy-labhackers is installed in has already been added into the OpenSesame paths. Someone in our lab also has successfully used labhackers to send triggers in PsychoPy, so I know that the port is functional.
How can I adjust the code to send triggers to a serial port in OpenSesame using pySerial or labhackers?

The problem is sorted out.
In OpenSesame, labhackers needs to be imported as:
pip install psychopy-labhackers
import psychopy.hardware.labhackers

